# move_uploaded_file multiple images last image not uploaded

Tags: php

I have a form with 4 file inputs for uploading images. It's uploading 3 files only and I can't figure out why.

The form:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="images[]">
    <input type="file" name="images[]">
    <input type="file" name="images[]">
    <input type="file" name="images[]">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
//On submit
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $imagesCount = (isset($_FILES['images']['name']) > 0 ? count($_FILES['images']['name']) : 0);
    $allowedExtenstions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'];
    $images_path = '../../uploads/images/';
    $errs = [];
    $errors = [];
    
    //Loop through 4 images
    for($i = 0; $i < $imagesCount; $i++){
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i])){
            $tmp_path = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $filename = $_FILES["images"]["name"][$i];
            $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            $newFileName = strtotime('now') . rand(0, 100) . $i . '.' . $extension;
            $size = $_FILES["images"]["size"][$i];
            $error = $_FILES["images"]["error"][$i];

            //Check size & extension
            if($size > 4194304) {
                $errors[] = 'Max file size 4MB';
                break;
            }elseif (!in_array($extension, $allowedExtenstions)) {
                $errors[] = 'Only images allowed';
                break;
            }else{
                //Save tmp_path, file name and errors in arrays
                $tmp_paths[] = $tmp_path;
                $file_names[] = $newFileName;
                $errs[] = $error;
            }
        }
    }

    //If no validation errors
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        //If 'uploads/images' path doesn't exists, Create it
        if (!is_dir($images_path)) {
            mkdir($images_path);
        }

        //Upload files from arrays
        for($i = 0; $i < $imagesCount; $i++){
            if(!move_uploaded_file($tmp_paths[$i], getcwd() . '\\' . $images_path . $file_names[$i])){
                //Print errors from $_FILES["images"]["error"]
                print_r($errs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`print_r($errs);` returns `Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 )`

There are no errors shown on the page.

What is the possible reason for this issue and how to debug it?

Comment: What is in `$imagesCount`, and in `$tmp_paths[]` and `$file_names[]` when you display them for debugging?

Comment: @droopsnoot `4`,  `Array ( [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpD91F.tmp [1] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpD920.tmp [2] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpD921.tmp [3] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpD922.tmp )` and `Array ( [0] => 165280747160.jpg [1] => 1652807471401.jpg [2] => 1652807471102.jpg [3] => 1652807471343.jpg )`

Comment: OK, and if you display debug information as you run through the loops, how many times does it execute each one? Do you have PHP error reporting enabled?

Comment: What is the purpose of using `getcwd()` in your target path? If you can correctly create the directory using `mkdir($images_path)`, then I don't see why prefixing that path with anything else should suddenly be necessary, when you move the file to that location.